# where to put Firestore trigger

Tags: typescript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to use Firestore DB trigger in my project, but it seems like it does not work. I am using Express.js for the router and functions are written in TypeScript.

**./apiRouter.ts**

```
import { test } from './controllers/test'

export let apiRouter = express.Router()

apiRouter.route('/test').post(test)
```

I've created a *test()* function, which creates a new city doc in 'cities' Firestore collection correctly:

**./controllers/test**

```
import { adminApp } from '../adminApp'

export const test = async (request, response) => {

  try {
   const res = await adminApp.firestore().collection('cities')
      .doc('LA')
      .set({
        name: "Los Angeles",
        state: "CA",
        country: "USA"
      })

    response.status(200).send(res)
  }
  catch (e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

and I initialize the FB admin app and write the 'citiesOnCreate' trigger like this:

**./adminApp.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
...

export const adminApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccountKeyCasted),
  databaseURL: databaseUrl
})

export const citiesOnCreate = functions.firestore
  .document('cities/{cityId}')
  .onCreate((change, context) => {
    console.log('citiesOnCreate: ', change, context)
  });
```

so when I post some data to that '/test' API endpoint, it creates new document in Firestore, but I cannot get the trigger to run.

EDIT: my **./index.ts** looks like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { apiRouter } from './apiRouter'
export { citiesOnCreate } from './adminApp'

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(apiRouter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions must be exported from the main entry point of your deployment, which is usually `index.ts`.  Right now, you're exporting `citiesOnCreate` from `adminApp.ts`, and it's not clear at all of your re-exporting it from the main entry point.  My guess is that you're not.

Comment: sorry, I've added additional info about my 'index.ts' file into the question. I guess I am exporting it correctly, or did I miss something?

Comment: ok, I was also expecting the console.log() to appear in terminal while serving the functions on my localhost. when I deployed the functions to live system, I can see the logs in Firebase 'Functions/logs' tab, so it looks like it works fine now, thanks